# Why don't I have a Web Application Option in Netbeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I am very new to Netbeans (I generally use Eclipse, but this is for class and we're doing everything with Netbeans) and have had a heck of a time configuring and setting it up. I am running Netbeans 8.2 with Tomcat 9.0. I thought I finally had everything working the way it is supposed to, so I moved on to my assignment.

I am supposed to create a servlet, however, the only option I have in Java Web is creating a .jsp page. I have no servlet or web application option. I have Java EE activated. I even deactivated and reactivated it. Am I missing something? Is it a faulty download?

Comment: When you create a web application with the NetBeans 8.2 project wizard it will only create **index.html** for you, but adding a servlet is trivial: [1] Select your web project in the **Projects** pane. [2] Right click, and from the context menu select **New > Servlet...** and complete the wizard. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you. All of the tutorials and chapters I read stated to use Java Web > Web Application. It was starting to stress me out that I couldn't find a way to do what they were doing as I followed along. In the end, I just ended up configuring Eclipse to do what I needed to complete the assignment.

Comment: OK. In case you use NetBeans in the future, this PDF article gives the basic details for creating a servlet in NetBeans 8.x: [Developing the First Servlet](https://cnx.org/resources/98fa78e3a83c674bfaa8899163d989b8f43f7089/01-FirstServlet.pdf)